# Select limited highest values from table A and order by table B

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a hard time writing a query that solves this problem.
My tables look like:

**Table A**

```
id | u_id | open | date
---+------+------+------------
 1 |    8 |   2  | 2017-07-20 (BBB)
 2 |  101 |   1  | 2017-07-20 (MMM)
 3 | 5475 |   3  | 2017-07-20 (WWW)
 4 |  147 |   1  | 2017-07-21 (PPP)
 5 |  149 |   1  | 2017-07-21 (QQQ)
 6 |  147 |   2  | 2017-07-16 (PPP)

(u_id being foreign key to Table B)
```

**Table B**

```
 id  | name | amm
-----+------+---
   4 | AAA  | 4
   5 | BBB  | 5
 101 | MMM  | 3
 110 | NNN  | 3
 146 | OOO  | 3
 147 | PPP  | 6
 149 | QQQ  | 3
5475 | WWW  | 2
```

The result I'm looking for needs to apply the the following rules:

1. Select ALL `id, names` from table B and
   `open, date` from table A (or NULL,NULL if `id` does not exist)
2. Only 1 result per name, with `MAX(date)` for Table A
3. WHERE: `open>1` on the `MAX(date)` in Table A
4. From those, select the top 50 highest `amm` from Table B
5. Return the result ordered by `name` alphabetically

So basically: everything from Table B, *excluding* id's in Table A where `open` for the LARGEST date from that id equals 1.

Let's say we LIMIT the selection to 4, then after rule 4. the result would be:

```
id   | name | open | date
-----+------+------+-----------
   5 | BBB  |  2   | 2017-07-20 //open>1,   nr.2 highest amm,
   6 | AAA  | NULL | NULL       //not in A, nr.3 highest amm, 
 110 | NNN  | NULL | NULL       //not in A, nr.4 highest amm, 
 146 | OOO  | NULL | NULL       //not in A, nr.6 highest amm, 

 NOT SELECTING:
 MMM: open =1
 PPP: at LARGEST date => open =1
 WWW: outside LIMIT
```

In the end, I'd like the result to be sorted alphabetically:

```
id   | name | open | date
-----+------+------+-----------
   6 | AAA  | NULL | NULL       
   5 | BBB  |  2   | 2017-07-20
 110 | NNN  | NULL | NULL
 146 | OOO  | NULL | NULL
```

At the moment, I have this query:

```
SELECT
    t3.id, 
    t3.name,
    t3.open,
    t3.amm,
    t3.date
    FROM(

    SELECT 
        t1.id, 
        t1.name,
        t1.amm,
        t2.open,
        MAX(t2.date) AS date
    FROM Table_B AS t1

    LEFT JOIN Table_A AS t2
    ON t1.id = t2.u_id
    AND (t2.open>1 OR t2.open IS NULL)

    GROUP BY t1.id
    ORDER BY t1.amm DESC,
    LIMIT 20
    ) AS t3
ORDER BY t3.name
```

This does give me a result ordered by `amm` and `name`.
What it **doesn't do** is filter the `date/open` combination correctly. It only takes the last `date` it finds for some `u_id`, not the `MAX(date)` with it's corresponding `open` value.

So the result still contains:

```
 147 | PPP  |  2  | 2017-07-16
```

despite there being also a

```
 147 | PPP  |  1  | 2017-07-19
```

Here is a [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93e95b/1).
`PPP` is in the results, where is shoudln't be.

Comment: Great effort, but see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry. Will do that, takes another half hour ;-)

Comment: It takes you half an hour to write out 12 lines of data? OK.

Comment: Added a fiddle.

Comment: Great. Can you amend the question to match the data set? Or vice versa.

Comment: @Strawberry: as much edited as possible.

Comment: I'm still completely baffled as to why there are some 20 odd rows in your fiddle but only 8 in the example above. This doesn't need to be complicated.

Comment: The only difference is the fiddle having 26 users, the example here has 8.

Answer (score 0):

I've given up trying to draw blood from this particular stone.

As far as I can tell you're after something like the following; I've renamed the tables to something fractionally more intelligible.

For the very last part, I'd just sort the resulting array in application code...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS log;

CREATE TABLE log
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,u_id INT NOT NULL
,open TINYINT NOT NULL
,date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO log VALUES
(1,   8,2,'2017-07-20'),
(2, 101,1,'2017-07-20'),
(3,5475,3,'2017-07-20'),
(4, 147,1,'2017-07-21'),
(5, 149,1,'2017-07-21'),
(6, 147,2,'2017-07-16');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE users
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,amm TINYINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES
(   4,'AAA',4),
(   5,'BBB',5),
( 101,'MMM',3),
( 110,'NNN',3),
( 146,'OOO',3),
( 147,'PPP',6),
( 149,'QQQ',3),
(5475,'WWW',2);

SELECT * 
  FROM users u 
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.*  
         FROM log x
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT u_id, MAX(date) date FROM log WHERE open > 1 GROUP BY u_id ) y
           ON y.u_id = x.u_id
          AND y.date = x.date
     ) l
    ON l.u_id = u.id
 ORDER 
    BY amm DESC LIMIT 50;

+------+------+-----+------+------+------+------------+
| id   | name | amm | id   | u_id | open | date       |
+------+------+-----+------+------+------+------------+
|  147 | PPP  |   6 |    6 |  147 |    2 | 2017-07-16 |
|    5 | BBB  |   5 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL       |
|    4 | AAA  |   4 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL       |
|  149 | QQQ  |   3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL       |
|  101 | MMM  |   3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL       |
|  110 | NNN  |   3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL       |
|  146 | OOO  |   3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL       |
| 5475 | WWW  |   2 |    3 | 5475 |    3 | 2017-07-20 |
+------+------+-----+------+------+------+------------+
```